# Command Prompt - Directory Listing function

Tags: command-line, ms-dos

Is there a way to produce a directory listing which only returns the first level of folders and none of the sub-folders? This list will then be outputted to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually non-recursive is the standard. If you only want directories, try this:

```
dir *.
```

In comparison this will list only directories but recursively:

```
dir *. /s
```

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed. I also added the /b switch to return the folder names only.